# Sending images using JavaScript Websockets to Flask server

Tags: javascript, html, flask, websocket, flask-socketio

**Overview**

1. A HTML5 page running on Flask using the getUserMedia API accesses the user/my webcam. (Done)
2. Every frame from the getUserMedia API video is drawn using Javascript canvas. (Done)
3. Every frame will be sent to the flask server as base64.
4. Every frame will then get sent from the flask server to a python file where the image is decoded.
5. The frames will be processed using OpenCV.

I'm using flask_socketio and Javascript websockets.
I'm new to Javascript and Websockets so apologies if the solution is obvious. I think the frames are being sent to the flask server (HTTP/1.1" 200). If they are being sent; it is sent every ~25secs however I want every frame to be sent immediately.

Any help is much appreciated.

HTML + JavaScript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.5/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <body onload="init();">
    <h1></h1>

     <p>
    <button onclick="startWebcam();">Start WebCam</button>
    <button onclick="stopWebcam();">Stop WebCam</button> 
    </p>
    <video onclick="snapshot(this);" width=400 height=400 id="video" controls autoplay></video>
  <p>

        Screenshots : <p>
      <canvas  id="myCanvas" width="400" height="350"></canvas>  
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">




        //--------------------
      // GET USER MEDIA CODE
      //--------------------
          navigator.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                             navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                             navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                             navigator.msGetUserMedia);

      var video;
      var webcamStream;

      function startWebcam() {
        if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
           navigator.getUserMedia (

              // constraints
              {
                 video: true,
                 audio: false
              },

              // successCallback
              function(localMediaStream) {
                 video = document.querySelector('video');
                 video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
                 webcamStream = localMediaStream;
              },

              // errorCallback
              function(err) {
                 console.log("The following error occured: " + err);
              }
           );
        } else {
           console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
        }  
      }

      function stopWebcam() {
        webcamStream.stop();
      }
      //---------------------
      // TAKE A SNAPSHOT CODE
      //---------------------
      var canvas, ctx;

      function init() {
        // Get the canvas and obtain a context for
        // drawing in it
        canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      }



      namespace = '/test';
            // Connect to the Socket.IO server.
            // The connection URL has the following format:
            //     http[s]://<domain>:<port>[/<namespace>]
      var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + namespace);
      timer = setInterval(
        function snapshot() {
         // Draws current image from the video element into the canvas
            ctx.drawImage(video, 0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            var frame = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            console.log(frame.substring(0, 50));
      }, 1000);

            // Event handler for new connections.
            // The callback function is invoked when a connection with the
            // server is established.
        socket.on('frame', function(data) {
            socket.emit('frame', frame);
        });   


  </script>
</html>
```

Flask server(updated)

```
async_mode = "eventlet"
from eventlet import wsgi, websocket
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, disconnect
import base64

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def cam():
    return render_template("liveweb1.html", async_mode=socketio.async_mode)

@socketio.on('frame', namespace='/test')
def user_video(frame):
    feed = frame
    print (str(feed))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.wrap_ssl(eventlet.listen(('', 8000)),
                              certfile='cert.crt',
                              keyfile='private.key',
                              server_side=True),
            app)
```

[Flask server screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ApLR.png)

[Eventlet server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYM7n.png)

Comment: You are using the Flask development server, which does not support WebSocket. Your connection is using long-polling, a less performant method. You may want to try installing eventlet for example, so that you can have websocket connections. That should improve the latency.

Comment: @Miguel Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the code however it doesn't seem to be sending the frames (see Eventlet server screenshot)

Comment: You are not going to see HTTP requests flying by in your console when you use Eventlet, because the connection switches to WebSocket. If the application isn't doing what it is supposed to do, you may want to check the browser console to see if there are any errors there.

Comment: So would you like to answer your question and tell me what's your final solution for sending video frame (not limit with flask)?